# Add elements to listbox on another page (Windows Phone 7) in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, windows-phone-7

net to make a Windows Phone application. I have a listBox on page1 called listBox1 and in page 2 I have a button called btnAdd. I want to be able to add an item into the listbox1 from page1 whenever btnAdd is pressed in page2. I knew how to do this on VB6 but it seems different on vb.Net. Can someone please help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about binding the listBox1 to a datasource that is available from both pages (maybe in a separate class) then updating that datasource from the btnAdd click event.

**Example:**

In Page1 add:

```
public static List<string> listItems = new List<string>();
```

In the OnNavigatedTo override add:

```
listBox1.ItemsSource = null;
listBox1.ItemsSource = listItems;
```

In Page2 btnAdd_Click handler add:

```
Page1.listItems.Add(textBox1.Text);
```

Sorry the above is C# but it shouldn't be difficult to get the VB equivalent.

Using the ViewModel approach and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged would be cleaner and avoid needing to reset the ItemSource in OnNavigatedTo.

Comment: btnAdd will add whatever text is in the textbox from page2, So i dont think this is possible

Comment: I'm not following you.  You can only view one of the pages at a time.  If you're on Page2 and click the button, in your btnAdd_Click handler you add the text to the datasource you've created (in a separate class so it's available to both pages).  The ListBox is bound to that datasource so when you go back to Page1 it should reflect the additional data.

Comment: Added simplified example to the answer.